I can't get creator's username with posts in MERN project
I am working on developing social media app using MERN Stack. First I made it to create post with img, description ans title and display in wall, it works well. but later I wanted to update it to display username with creator's name. Now I get message 'Error fetching from server'. this is my post schema and user schema.
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    img: [{type:String}],
    title: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
    description: {type:String},
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    comments: [CommentSchema],
    react: [ReactionSchema]
    
},
{timestamps: true}
    );

 module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);


const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type: String, required:true},
    secondname: {type: String, required:true},
    email:{type:String, required:true, unique: true },
    password: {type:String, required:true},
    age:{type:String},
    profilePicture: { type: String },
    isAdmin:{
        type: Boolean, default:false
    }

},
{timestamps: true}
    );



const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;

this is the front end.
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Filter from './Filter';
import SocialPost from './SocialPost';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Wall() {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => { 

  
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getPosts')
    .then(res => {
      if(res.data.status === 'success' && res.data.data.posts){
        const Posts = res.data.data.posts;
        setPosts(Posts);
      }else{
        setError('Unexpected response format from server');
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if(err.response && err.response.status === 403){
        setError('Access Denied');
      }else{
        setError('Error fetching from server');
      }
    });
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col> <Filter/> </Col>
        
        <Col xs={6}>
        <div style={{ maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 100px)", overflowY: "auto" }}>
          <SocialPost/>
          {
        posts.map((post,index) => (
        <SocialPost
        key = {index}
        img = {post.img}
        title = {post.title}
        description = {post.description}
        username={post.user.username} 
        id = {post._id}
        
        
        />
      ))}
       {error && <p style={{color:'red'}}>{error}</p>}
        </div>
      </Col>
      
        <Col>3 of 3</Col>
      </Row>
     </Container>
    </>
  )
}



import React from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";
//import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';

const SocialPost = ({img,title,description, username}) => {
  return ( 
    <>
      <Card style={{ width: "38rem" , margin:"10px"}}>
        <Card.Header variant="dark">
          <Image src="fgh" roundedCircle className="me-2 avatar-sm" />
          Artist Name{" "}
          {username}
        </Card.Header>
        <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
          <ListGroup.Item><Card.Title>{title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            {description}
          </Card.Text></ListGroup.Item>
        </ListGroup>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={img} />
        <Card.Body>
         <Card.Text className="size=sm">12 views</Card.Text>
          <Card.Text>
          
            <i class="bi bi-chat"></i> Comment
          </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default SocialPost;


This is the back end.
const router = require("express").Router();
const Post = require("../Database/models/posts")


router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
    
    
    try {
        const posts = await Post.find({}).populate('author', 'firstname secondname');
        const formattedPosts = posts.map(post => ({
            ...post._doc,
            user: {
                firstname: post.author.firstname,
                secondname: post.author.secondname,
                username: `${post.author.firstname} ${post.author.secondname}`
            }
        }));

        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: {
                posts: formattedPosts
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            status: 'Failed',
            message: err.message
        });
    }
});

module.exports = router;

Please help me to find issue here and correct it.

Welcome to SO @WADD, This question should be updated to include desired behaviour, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Hi, The code looks good. It might be a very minor missing. As you know, the present error 'Error fetching from server' comes from the  statement  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getPosts'), please show us the route handler getPosts to discuss further.

You should not be else-ing in a successful fetch and checking && res.data.data.posts in the same if statement that checks for a successful network request.
If you're using array of errors, the variable should be called errors, not error.
Your Post.find({}) should be passed in a req data. It seems empty right now.
You should also explicitly handle a case of a null formattedPosts result.
Lastly, please post a network tab result of the request. The only information that we get from your post above is that the client request is failing, but not because of 403.
To me, it is unclear which part of the req/res chain is causing your record is failing. But above modifications should get you closer to the source.

Potential Issues and Debugging

Backend Endpoint: Ensure the backend endpoint is correctly set up to respond at http://localhost:5000/getPosts.
Network Issues: Verify no network issues or CORS issues are blocking the request.
Database Entries: Ensure that posts in the database have a valid author field that references a valid user.
Console Logs: Check both the browser's console and the server logs for any errors or messages that might give more insight into what's going wrong.

You haven't mentioned CORS in the code snippets you provided. CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is necessary if your frontend and backend run on different origins (e.g., ports like localhost:3000 for frontend and localhost:5000 for backend).
To enable CORS in your Express backend, you can use the CORS middleware.
